# Does the method to derive axes length of $2$-D ellipse by converting its polynomial equation to the canonical form generalize to $n$-Dimensions?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, analytic-geometry, quadratics, conic-sections, matrix-equations

I refer to the article [Matrix representation of conic sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections) in Wikipedia. It is shown that a conic section in 2D will satisfy a second-degree polynomial equation:
$$
Q(x, y) = Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0
$$
This can be then expressed in matrix form:
$$
f =
\begin{pmatrix} x& y\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} A & B/2\\ B/2 & C \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}
+ 
\begin{pmatrix} D & E \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}
+ F = 0
$$
or in homogeneous coordinates:
$$
f =
\begin{pmatrix} x & y & 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} A & B/2 & D/2\\ B/2 & C & E/2 \\ D/2 & E/2 & F \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
= 0
$$

Let $A_{33} = \begin{pmatrix} A & B/2\\ B/2 & C \end{pmatrix}$, and $A_Q = \begin{pmatrix} A & B/2 & D/2\\ B/2 & C & E/2 \\ D/2 & E/2 & F \end{pmatrix}$.

If $det(A_{33}) > 0$, then the equation is an ellipse. This equation can then be converted to the canonical form of a centered ellipse as such:
$$
\lambda_1 x^2 + \lambda_2 y^2 = -\frac{det(A_Q)}{det(A_{33})}
$$

$$
a^2 = -\frac{det(A_Q)}{\lambda_1 det(A_{33})},\; b^2 = -\frac{det(A_Q)}{\lambda_2 det(A_{33})}
$$
where $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues of $A_{33}$, and $a$ and $b$ are the lengths of the axes of the ellipse.

**My question is, does this generalize to $n$-Dimensions hyper-ellipsoids?** In the $n$-D case, $A_{33}$ will be a $n \times n$ matrix and $A_Q$ a $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix.

- Firstly, does a positive $det(A_{33})$ indicate an hyper-ellipsoid
  rather than other types of hyper-conics?
- Secondly, will the lengths, $L_i$ of the $n$ axes of the
  hyper-ellipsoid also be found as $L_i^2 = -\frac{det(A_Q)}{\lambda_i
     det(A_{33})}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $n$-dimensions, let $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n $, then you be given the equation of the hyper-conic as

$ \mathbf{x}^T {Q} \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{b} + c = 0 $

Assuming $Q$ is invertible, then you can find the center of this hyper-conic as follows

$ \mathbf{x}_0 = - \dfrac{1}{2} Q^{-1} \mathbf{b} $

And the equation can be re-written using this center as follows

$ ( \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0 )^T Q (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0) = {\mathbf{x}_0}^T Q \mathbf{x}_0 - c $

The next thing to do, is diagonalize $Q$ and write it as

$ Q = R D R^T $

where $R$ is a rotation matrix.  Substituting this gives

$ ( \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0 )^T R D R^T (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0) = {\mathbf{x}_0}^T Q \mathbf{x}_0 - c $

If Q is positive definite, i.e. all the diagonal entries of $D$ are positive, and the right hand side of the above equation is positive, then define the matrix $E$ as follows

$ E = \dfrac{D}{{\mathbf{x}_0}^T Q \mathbf{x}_0 - c} $

Then

$ ( \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0 )^T R E R^T (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0) = 1 $

Further define the vector $ \mathbf{v} = R^T (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0) $

Then

$ \mathbf{v}^T E \mathbf{v} = 1 $

And this is the standard equation of the hyper-conic, in this case, hyper-ellipse.  The diagonal entries of the diagonal matrix $E$ are the reciprocal of the squares of the semi-axes lengths of the hyper-ellipse.  That is,

$ E = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{s_1^2} && 0 && \dots && 0 \\0 && \dfrac{1}{s_2^2} && \dots && 0 \\ \vdots && \vdots && \ddots && \vdots \\ 0 && 0 && \dots && \dfrac{1}{s_n}^2 \end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed! Your derivation is easier to understand than the one in the wiki article. Because $diag(D)$ would be the eigenvalues of $Q$, it seems that $x_0^TQx_0-c$ is equal to the $-\frac{det(A_Q)}{det(A_{33})}$ term in the derivation given in the wiki article. Do you know what is the meaning of the fraction of determinants of those 2 matrices?

Comment: No idea.  Sorry.